# Logging a variable change to the console in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I write a while loop, I'd end the loop by changing a boolean variable from true to false it logs "false" to the console. Most recently I've run into this code on Codecademy:

```
var slaying = true;
// A bit of new math magic to calculate the odds
// of hitting the dragon. We'll cover this soon!
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying) {
  if (youHit) {
    console.log("You hit the dragon and did " + damageThisRound + " damage!");
    totalDamage += damageThisRound;

    if (totalDamage >= 4) {
      console.log("You did it! You slew the dragon!");
      slaying = false;
    } else {
      youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("The dragon burninates you! You're toast.");
    slaying = false;
  }
}
```

The program runs fine, but at the end it logs "false", anyone know what is going on?

Comment: For me at the end it does *not* log "false" nor is there anything about the code that indicates that it ever might.  Sure you don't have a statement such as `console.log(slaying)` beneath the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a bug/feature in CodeAcademy's javascript engine where it prints the last while loop's condition when it ends.

The following code piece will print `true` to the console even though I do not log it.

```
var slaying = true;

while (slaying) {
    console.log("slaying");
    slaying = false;
}

while(!slaying){
    console.log("not slaying..");
    slaying = true;
}
```

So in my opinion it is simply a bug.

(I also got one saying I had to capitalize the m in `Math.floor()` even though it was. It was parsing the word math in the comments as actual code).